# Google Search Console change of address tool is not listing my new .org domain despite verifying it, how do I change to it from my .in domain?

Tags: seo, google, domains, google-search-console, google-search

I have moved my website to dot org (.org) from dot in (.in) to rank globally and made a redirection from old domain to new domain but how can I inform this to Google.

I have added my new domain in Google Webmaster tools but unable to change address from dot in (.in) to dot org (.org).

In webmaster tools -> Change site address, does not allow me to select my new domain.

Here is the list of domain I have added in Google search console.

[image]

Comment: Have you added both domain in your search console account? On your old search console property you can select new domain if you've already added 301 redirection properly. Please attach screenshot, it's hard to understand what you're doing wrong. Hope you already read [help support article](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en) on that.

Comment: @Goyllo Yes, I have added. I have attached screenshot please check. My old domain is seeken.in & new domain is seeken.org

Comment: I want to see screenshot of change of address tool to know why you can't select a domain name.

Answer (score 2):

The change of address tool works only if you verified both domains as owner. It's not a problem if it doesn't work for some reason, there are more important things than the 'change of address tool', which are:

- set up canonicals, alternate hreflangs, titles, descriptions, robots.txt and so on at the new domain
- fetch & render the main pages on the new domain and add them to the index
- set up 301 redirects. Prevent multiple 301s after each other. Try to set it up like domainA.com/a --> domainB.com/b

If you checked all these things, you can check and try search console to use the change of address tool. But Google will see the 301's the next time they crawl the old site. You can also try to fetch&render -> index the old domain when you have set up everything. That's another way to let Google know you moved your site.

Additional read: site move recommendations in Google's helpcenter: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34437?hl=en

Comment: "You can also try to fetch&render -> index the old domain when you have set up everything. That's another way to let Google know you moved your site." - this is the most helpful info I've found, especially in light of the fact that the change of address tool doesn't seem to be something they are going to migrate to the new version of the Search Console.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the same issue for my site. Change of address 2nd step was not showing any site to choose.

I went to the homepage and submitted my new site with "Add a property." It automatically get verified and then I went back to my old site, it started showing the new site option.

Note: we have to verify the site on Google search console homepage, as it is a brand new site.